# Parse saveAll counts as separate requests for quota?

Tags: parse-platform

Using the JS SDK I have a `Parse.Object.saveAll` which ends up calling into `/batch`. I see those requests take about 300ms each and it just iterates over a slice of 20 objects at a time. Part way though, after ~86 requests I get the error

```
Result: {"code":155,"message":"This application performed 1819 requests within the past minute, and exceeded its request limit. Please retry in one  minute or raise your request limit."}
```

I'm not doing anything else in my app, I just want to flush a bunch of data into objects. I thought request limits was for the frontend servers not the object store.

How can I go about making a few thousand objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Paul this is not good news for you. With parse a query counts as 1 API request, including for local datastore, and then updating or saving objects count as 1, even if your doing it through a query. See the first [FAQ Here](https://parse.com/plans/faq) for reference. I believe the only thing that doesn't count against you is cached data/queries, which makes sense since it's already used an API request to retrieve it. So unfortunately there is no getting around it.

Comment: So does `saveAll` count as single request or as many as the objects in array? I can't find any information about it.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev they count as individual saves. There is no documentation on it that I can find either but it's just simple math. Just use Paul's example. Parse API requests are actually based on a per minute basis, they just give you the average per second request limit so you can plan accordingly. If your app is set to 30 API requests per second you'll top out at 1800 requests a minute __not 30 p/s__ which is why he got that error. You can't duplicate that if saveAll is one conjoined request. It's saving different properties to different objects each object so yes they are individual.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev you could always email them for clarification. Or check ask on the Google groups forum they use